# Count num of documents result of a query with ReactiveMongo (play 2.7 and scala 2.12)

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm using the latest ReactiveMongo for play 2.7 and scala 2.12:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.17.1-play27"
```

and I want to create a find query and to count the number of documents returned from this query...

something like:

```
def countEntriesForReport(reportId: String) = {
    collection.find( Json.obj("reportId" -> reportId), Option.empty[BSONDocument]).count()
  }
```

But unfortunately there is no count here... how would you do that?

Comment: What's the return type? If it's some sort of collection like a List, you could just do a `.size` or `.length` or something on it

Comment: In the past I've done stuff like `postsCollection.flatMap(_.find(Json.obj(), None)(JsObjectWriter, JsObjectWriter).cursor[Post]().collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[Post]]())).map(_.size)` (`postsCollection` is a `Future[BSONCollection]` and I'm looking for a List of documents which map to `Post` case classes in this example). This example is c&p from a Play 2.5.19 project I bodged together a while ago though so reactivemongo might've changed since then

Comment: Rather `.count(query)`

Answer (score -1):

How about using a `Cursor` ?

I think this will be solve your issue:

```
  def countEntriesForReport(reportId: String): Future[List[User]] = {
    // the cursor of documents
    val found = collection.map(_.find(selector = Json.obj("reportId" -> reportId),
      projection = Option.empty[BSONDocument]).cursor[User]())

    // build (asynchronously) a list containing all of the users
    found.flatMap(_.collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[User]]()))
  }

// Now using the function
countEntriesForReport("85").map(list => println("Count: " + list.size))
```

This function will return the result of the query as a `Future` of `List[User]`. So we should use `.map` after function call to resolve the *Future* result and then get the size of it.

I was tested this code with *ReactiveMongo* version `0.16.2`. Hopefully it will work with `0.17.1` as well.